# boost serialization of dynamic arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, serialization, boost, dynamic-arrays

I have code looking something like this:

```
struct DataStruct
{
//  some fields here
};

class C1
{
public:
    C1(size_t n)
    {
        ptrData = new DataStruct[n];
        ptrPtrs = new DataStruct*[n];
        for(size_t i=0;i<n;i++)
            ptrPtrs[i] = &ptrData[i];
    }

    virtual ~C1() 
    {
        delete[] ptrData;
        delete[] ptrPtrs;
    }

    DataStruct* ptrData;
    DataStruct** ptrPtrs;
};
```

and need it to be serialized preferably by boost::serialization. I have not found ways to save dynamically allocated arrays except saving it item by item in loop. But not sure how to save second array - array of pointers. Is it possible to do it more or less convenient way in boost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible for boost to know the number of elements as all you have is a pointer. The heap manager knows how many elements to delete when you call delete[] but it is not made available to code like `boost::serialize`

Of course your best bet is to use a `std::vector` in the first place, but failing that, create a "wrapper" class that can be used for serialization, both inbound and outbound.

If we call it ArrayWrapper and template it

```
template< typename T >
struct ArrayWrapper
{
   T* data = nullptr;
   size_t size = 0;
   ArrayWrapper() = default;
   ArrayWrapper( T* data_, size_t size_ ) : data( data_ ), size( size_ ) {}
};
```

Now you can serialize one from a pointer and the known size by first writing the size, then each item.

When serializing back, you first read the size, then allocate the number of objects and then reading them in.

Of course you need to manage your memory and using `std::vector` is a far better option.

In general, you do not store "pointers" you store the data they point to. when read back out of the archive, you are not going to get the same pointers that went in, you will get the same data back.

For that purpose, you actually just archive the outer one (array of pointers) and get it to call ArrayWrapper on the inner one.

Comment: well, i hoped serialization have some kind of adapter allowing to specify array length, like in my answer above. vector is not an option here, since, as i remember it does not guarantee what elements won't be moved internally, so it is not possible to store pointers to vector items.

Comment: Your vector elements will not be moved if you do not modify the size of your vector in any way, and if you reserve up front it will never move them.

Comment: You can also store vectors of smart-pointers. Even if the elements in the vector move, the items they point to will not and your smart-pointers will remain valid. You can use shared_ptr for this and if you are careful, unique_ptr, but not auto_ptr.

Comment: smart pointers is not an option too, since it could be huge arrays (tens of gigabytes long) with very frequent access, some any exceed memory usage will decrease useful memory usage ratio and wrappers will slow down work a lot. will think about vectors again, thank you.

Comment: If they don't have to be stored in contiguous memory you may find that deque offers a better solution to vector. Still random access but you may find you can hold a higher capacity before you run out of memory.

The excess baggage you get by using vector rather than arrays is constant (i.e. it doesn't increase with the number of items your vector has).

If it is a vector of vectors, you can pack your inner ones.